# 400 bad request from rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-methods, rest-api

Whenever I go to cart page or checkout page after adding products, `console` always throws `400 Bad Request`. I tried reinstalling Magento and did many things but there is no luck. Estimate shipping address section keep on loading and it doesn't return anything.

Request URL: `http://******.com/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods`

The following is the Request Payload:

```
{address: {country_id: "US"}}
address
:
{country_id: "US"}
country_id
:
"US"
```

I really don't understand whats happening with this request. What is missing here? What should be the response?

It would be much appreciated if someone provides me an answer.

-Thanks

Comment: Have you pass the authentication in this API call. Please use post master chrome tool for this

Answer (score 0):

I was using **PHP** lower version(5.9.x) as it is not supported for magento latest version. I just verified the server's software(apache, mysql) versions and **upgraded to the newer version**. And also **restarted the server**. Now it works fine. Thanks for your all of your support.

Comment: How did lower version specifically affect this version? Did you find something in the logs that pointed to an unsupported function? How did you trace down the issue? Thanks.

Comment: As you know, magento 2 works on above php 7+ as some of the functions are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue - rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods.
At checkout page shipping methods were not displaying. I solved this issue by updating composer. This is issue with Magento_Amqp ,Magento_MysqlMq and Temando_Shipping modules.

Run the command below and re-deploy magento.

```
composer update

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by 2 method:-

1. Disable manage stock here

   admim>stores>configuration>catalog>inventory>Product stock option>manage stock-->NO

or

Correct solution: (Using phpmyadmin, run this sql query)
2. You need to change sales Order Prefix or Sufix ID as following:-

```
UPDATE sales_sequence_profile SET suffix= X WHERE meta_id = 5;
```

Here suffix= XYZ  name of your choise.